# Little Fermat's theorem question $135^{135} mod 17$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Since $17$ is prime, $135^{16} \equiv 1 \bmod 17$ from Fermat's little theorem.

Then we are left with $135^7 \bmod 17$, how is it calculated?

Comment: Was $13^7$ a typo for $135^7$?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

Since $135=8\times 17 -1$, the remainder is $17-1=16$. In fact, we didn't really need FLT.

Answer (score 1):

$13^2=169=170-1$. Therefore $13^6 =17k-1$ and $13^7=17k-13.$  Thus the answer is $4$

Answer (score 0):

$135\equiv 16\equiv \mathbf {-1} \bmod 17$, so:

- $135^{\text{even}}\equiv 1\bmod 17$,  and
- $135^{\text{odd}}\equiv -1\bmod 17$.